# where to check "If Im using v4.29.0 or higher of the SDK, you instead need to add:"

Tags: ios

in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9?locale=en_US it says:-

If you're using v4.29.0 or higher of the SDK, you instead need to add:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

how can i know what is my SDK version ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just find the framework you are using and check Info.plist file inside it. You will find `Bundle version` field there - it is the version. For example, if it is Facebook SDK, you should have FBSDKCoreKit.framework in your project folder, just open it in Finder as a folder and you will find Info.plist there.

Btw, you can find the version of any dependency in your dependency manager (if you use it). For example if you use pods, there is a file `Podfile.lock` with information about used frameworks and versions.

Comment: i have upload img up i fund Bundle version = 1 . is it what you mean ?

Comment: you posted Info.plist of your project, but you need to check Info.plist of Facebook framework. So ok, you use Cocoapods. Find `Podfile.lock` file in your projects folder (in the same folder as `Podfile`) open it and you will find something like: `- Crashlytics (3.10.1):` about you Facebook SDK

Comment: yeah now i found it   - FBSDKLoginKit (4.34.0)
thank you so much